# Taming the x-axis labels of a multi-level pandas dataframe maptlotlib .plot() call

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have pandas dataframe with multi-level row index composed of two `datetime` values.

I plot various slices of the dataframe. (they're slices of the inner level).

My problem is that the x-axis labels have too much detail. The label includes both levels of the index, and uses a format string that includes 00:00:00 time.    I only need to use the outer level (`index[0].values`) and I don't care about the time fragment.  I highlighted in red the parts I don't want.

[image]

What's the most-efficient way I could give a different index (that looks like what I want) to the `.plot()`?  Can I do it without messing with the dataframe itself?

```
#create the main dataframe
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-1-1', end = '2010-12-31', freq='m')
dt2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2011-1-1', end = '2011-1-10', freq='d')
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dt,dt2], names=['assessment_date', 'contract_date'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=mi)
df['foo']=7

df.plot(rot=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the ticklabels for a multiindex dataframe are anyways fixed, you may just loop over them and truncate their text to whatever you want.

```
trunc = lambda x: x.strip("()").split(" ")[0]
tl = [ trunc(t.get_text()) for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(tl)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create the main dataframe
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-1-1', end = '2010-12-31', freq='m')
dt2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2011-1-1', end = '2011-1-10', freq='d')
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dt,dt2], names=['assessment_date', 'contract_date'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=mi)
df['foo']=np.random.rand(len(df))

ax = df.plot(rot=50)

trunc = lambda x: x.strip("()").split(" ")[0]
tl = [ trunc(t.get_text()) for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(tl)

plt.show()
```

[image]